# Edge inspect element button does nothing

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-devtools

The inspect element button in Edge (Ctrl+Shift+C) does exactly nothing when clicked.

[image: Inspect button]

Repros 100% for me for about a year. Affects all pages including this one, Google's homepage, etc. Chrome inspect works on all the same pages, but certain contrived scenarios I started running into make it inconvenient to not have it working on Edge.

Windows 10 (Home) Version 22H2 (Build 19045.2364)
Edge version 97.0.1072.55 (Official build) (64-bit)

I'm running on a clean version of Windows without any third-party windows integrations, antivirus or hotkey remappers. It still repros when my browser extensions are turned off.

There isn't much about this online. One solution suggested going to edge://flags/#edge-overlay-scrollbars-win-style and turning off minimal scrollbars, but that didn't solve it. I'm looking for a solution that allows the inspect button to function again.

Comment: This concerns devtools in Edge. F12/inspect are not the same. I used the tag for google-chrome-devtools since there's no edge equivalent. I think that tag might need scope reevaluated to include edge?

Comment: Which Edge version is it? I assume you're clicking multiple times on the button? As sometimes it doesn't respond for some reason and that's a problem in most Chromium-based browsers. Did you try simple debugging such as reinstalling?

Comment: any number of clicks, on any day for about a year. It's been a long time coming to post this question. Edge version is definitely important, I'll update that in the question, thanks!

Comment: Your Edge is very outdated. 113 is the current version. Tr upgrading instead of reinstalling then.

Comment: Ah, maybe that was it. Edge doesn't normally update over metered connections it looks like, and it's currently working. There might've been some issue with that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Edge is very outdated, `97` was released in [January 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-release-schedule#microsoft-edge-releases). Current version is `114`. Upgrading outdated software should be one of the 1st steps to debug problems, unless you need to use a version specifically for some reason. Also, keeping web browsers outdated is not safe, as security patches are quite common part of their development. I recommend a package manager like [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) to keep track of outdated software.

Issues in quite old software are hard to debug as not many people will be running that version and installer for a ~1.5 year old version seems to be unfindable in trustable sources in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It work like this :

- Click the button
- Move the pointer until it hovers over the element to inspect
- Click the element or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit this mode.
  The object stays selected.

Comment: It does, however as stated in the first sentence, the inspect element button does exactly nothing when clicked. You might deduce I know how this works from the fact I'm using the Chrome devtools :)

Comment: You're not supplying enough information - you should demonstrate a website where the above procedure doesn't work. Without something concrete, we'll keep on talking only generalities.